# unable to override application.conf in play 2.6.6 scala

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt

I wanted different `application.conf` and `logback.xml` for production and development environment.

I found few ways and tried it. But none of them worked for me:

1. Sbt run command
2. PlayKeys.devSettings
3. JavaOption in run

Please help me understand what mistake I am making.

I tried following things

```
PlayKeys.devSettings := Seq("""play.server.http.port""" -> "8080","""-Dlogger.file""" -> "C:/Playworkspaces/conf/dev-logback.xml","""-Dconfig.file""" -> "C:/Playworkspaces/conf/devApplication.conf")

PlayKeys.devSettings := Seq("play.server.http.port" -> "8080","-Dlogger.file" -> "conf/dev-logback.xml","-Dconfig.file" -> "conf/devApplication.conf")

sbt run -Dlogger.file->C:/Playworkspaces/conf/dev-logback.xml
```

All things tried with and without (conf/devApplication.conf, devApplication.conf) full path.

Thanks[image]

Answer (score 1):

When using `PlayKeys.devSettings`, do not write `-D` prefix, for example, it should be

```
"config.file" -> "C:/Playworkspaces/conf/devApplication.conf"
```

instead of

```
"-Dconfig.file" -> "C:/Playworkspaces/conf/devApplication.conf"
```

On a side note, I can see you placed DEV config in the filesystem instead of the classpath. If DEV config is not containing any secrets, my suggestion would be to put it on the classpath under `app/conf/devApplication.conf` and provided it via `config.resource`:

```
PlayKeys.devSettings := Seq("config.resource" -> "devApplication.conf")
```

Comment: Thanks for replying . I tried without -D and it was also not working.

Comment: Do you have github where we could see your code? Try debugging by executing `sbt -Dconfig.trace=loads run`. This flag prints the full path of all the config files that actually get loaded.

Answer (score 0):

There is a small Exception in `sbt run -Dlogger.file->C:/Playworkspaces/conf/dev-logback.xml`

It should be `=`.

As Mario explained put the extra config files also in the conf directory (classpath).

With that try:

`sbt run -Dlogger.resource=dev-logback.xml -Dconfig.resource=devApplication.conf`

Here additional info:

- [ProductionConfiguration#Logging-configuration](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ProductionConfiguration#Logging-configuration)
- [ProductionConfiguration#Specifying-an-alternate-configuration-file](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ProductionConfiguration#Specifying-an-alternate-configuration-file)

Comment: Thanks for replying. I tried sbt run -Dlogger.resource=dev-logback.xml -Dconfig.resource=devApplication.conf and it is still not working

Comment: please add a screenshot from your project structure (expanded conf directory) to your question

Comment: added image to original question. Please have a look

Comment: I would guess that you have sub-projects - what returns `sbt projects`?